# How do I tell video.js which mp4 source to use for mobile?

Tags: video.js

I have two mp4 source files, one encoded for desktop and one for mobile.  Video.js is serving the wrong one to iPhone and iPad and they cannot be played. How can I tell Video.js which one to serve to these devices?

--Edit to add more info and clarify:--

I am using Video.js version 3.2.0, but the same problem occurs in 4.0.

The reproducible problem I am having is that some videos are not playing on older iOS devices - 1st gen iPad and iPhone 3GS. I believe it is because Video.js is playing the first mp4 in the source list instead of the one encoded for mobile.

My Video.js player code looks like this:

```
<video id="video_1" class="video-js vjs-default-skin" 
     controls preload="auto" width="640" height="390" 
          poster="https://s3.amazonaws.com/sightingsreport/videos/1748/dthumbnail_0000.png"
          data-setup="{}">
          <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/sightingsreport/videos/1748/default.mp4" 
                type='video/mp4' />
          <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/sightingsreport/videos/1748/movie.webm" 
                type='video/webm' />
          <source src="https://s3.amazonaws.com/sightingsreport/videos/1748/mobile.mp4" 
                type='video/mp4' />
</video>
```

If I move the mobile.mp4 source to be first in the list, it plays on the old iOS devices, but it also appears to use that one on non-mobile devices.

I thought Video.js was supposed to automatically serve the best source file for the device. Is that not correct?

What is the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i would do it with php like ..

```
<?PHP
$isiPod = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPod");
$isiPhone = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPhone");
$isiPad = stripos($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT'],"iPad");
$isiDevice = $isiPod || $isiPhone || $isiPad ;
?>
```

..and..

```
    <video id="video_player" class="video-js vjs-default-skin">
 <?PHP if($isiDevice ) { ?>
    <source src="mobile.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
 <?PHP } else { ?>
    <source src="desktop.mp4" type='video/mp4' />
 <?PHP } ?>
    </video>
```

Comment: I went with a similar server-side approach, although I was really expecting there to be some way for video.js to handle this without getting into specific http user agents on the server. Anyhoo - thanks!

Answer (score 2):

This is a ***major bug*** in `video.js`. It checks for `canPlayType()` on each of the sources and select only the first one to use instead of keeping the multiple sources that the browser can select from.

Basically, it's impossible right now to have a fallback video of the same type.

I've submitted an issue on Github related to this:

https://github.com/videojs/video.js/issues/662